# Cayley tree reachable nodes proof

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, symmetry, network, cayley-graphs

Imagine being in the central node of a Cayley Tree graph like this one: [Cayle Tree, K =3 and D = 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdJzr.png)

For a number of reachable t steps (t<D) prove that the reacheable nodes from the center equal:

> $$ N_t = \frac {K(K-1)^t -2}{K-2}$$

P.S. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.